# Airflow KubernexExecutor doens't spaw KubernetesPodOperator tasks and complete successfully

Tags: airflow

I'm testing kubernetes pod operator running
Airflow 2.2.1 with kubernetes cnf 2.1.0 on my minikube.

I'm having issues trying to spaw a mock task:

```py
      init_environments = [
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name='AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__POD_TEMPLATE_FILE', value='""'),
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name='KUBERNETES__POD_TEMPLATE_FILE', value='""'),
        k8s.V1EnvVar(name='POD_TEMPLATE_FILE', value='""')]
    other_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="ingestion_kube",
        env_vars=init_environments,
        cmds=["bash", "-cx"],
        arguments=["echo 10 \n\n\n\n\n\n\n"],
        name="base",
        image="meltano-flieber",
        image_pull_policy="IfNotExists",
        in_cluster=True,
        namespace="localkubeflow",
        is_delete_operator_pod=False,
        pod_template_file=None,
        get_logs=True
    )
```

The task pod from KubernetesExecutor that executes the airflow completes successfully but there is no sign of the pod operator task.

Relevant logs of airflow task:

```
[2021-11-23 21:30:28,213] {dagbag.py:500} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/***/dags/meltano/meltano_ingest_pendo.py
Running <TaskInstance: meltano_tasks.ingestion_kube manual__2021-11-23T21:30:10.788963+00:00 [queued]> on host meltanotasksingestionkube.996b19ee10464c2f8683cdfc8ce7303
```

And in airflow tha task looks like if failed but without any relevant logs, anybody have something related to that or has any suggestions?